# How to set a standard image to show if a search for associated image name yields no results?

Tags: java, image, search

I am working on a project for my course and have been asked to show an associated image for products in a system, the user can add products, and he enters the name of the image file whilst doing so. the program then finds the image file and displays it with the product information.

I would like to add some additional code so that if there is no image file matching the string input that a standard image is shown. The code I have so far either shows the image file if it is found or does not show anything. can someone show me how to modify it so that it can show a standard image if no associated image file is found. the standard image is simply "no-image-found.jpg". Here is the code:

```
 public void showImage(JLabel imageArea, String image){



BufferedImage img = null;
try {    
    img = (BufferedImage)ImageIO.read(new File(image));
    Image actualimage = img.getScaledInstance(imageArea.getWidth(), imageArea.getHeight(), 0);
    imageArea.setIcon(new ImageIcon(actualimage));
    } 
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }          
}
```

any help is very much appreciated, and my sincere apologies if this is a noob question, I am quite new to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the catch, you could load the standard image and show it

Answer (score 1):

Basically check for image existence assuming path is valid otherwise get the standard image. You can have something similar:

```
    public void showImage(JLabel imageArea, String image)
    {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try
        {
            file = new File(image);

            if (file.exists())
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(file);
            }
            else
            {
                file = new File(standardImagePath);
                img = ImageIO.read(file);
            }

            Image actualimage = img.getScaledInstance(imageArea.getWidth(), imageArea.getHeight(), 0);
            imageArea.setIcon(new ImageIcon(actualimage));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```